# osticket staff id becomes 0 after closing the ticket

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to the osticket,when someone creates ticket there is staffid but upon closing the ticket staffid against the ticket goes to zero.

structure of ost_ticket table is

```
ticket_id,ticketID,dept_id,sla_id,priority_id,topic_id,staff_id,team_id,email,name,subject,helptopic,phone,phone_ext,ip_address,status,isoverdue,isanswered,duedate,ropened,closed,lastmessage,lastresponse,created,updated.
```

As i want to know who closed the ticket and time duration taken by single staff member to close the ticket.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: We don't see any code. Show us the query that updates the table when you close a ticket for starters.

Comment: Can you please add some information on what you're doing, what's the relevant code and/or how the problems are arising?

Comment: This is by default functionality of osticket as somecloses the ticket,the staff id against the ticket becomes zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution over here

```
ost_ticket_event table over there log is maintained of 
Assigned ticket
closed ticket
created ticket
```

along with `staffid` ,`dept_id`, `team_id`

also we can obtain the timestamp